# exception when running jpa query with DTO and join fetch

Tags: hibernate, jpa, projection, dto

I am trying to run a query with join fetch but I am also using DTO projection to improve performance but I am getting the exception below:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the
>   owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list
>   [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy
>   properties,classAlias=pi,role=returnitRest.Ereturn.productItems,tableName=product_item,tableAlias=productite1_,origin=ereturn
>   ereturn0_,columns={ereturn0_.id ,className=returnitRest.ProductItem}}]
>   [SELECT DISTINCT new returnitRest.Ereturn(e.rma, e.shipper, e.carrier,
>   e.returnAction) FROM returnitRest.Ereturn e JOIN FETCH e.productItems
>   pi WHERE e.status = 'RECEIVED' AND e.shipper.email = :shipper AND
>   e.carrier.email = :carrier AND pi.returnAction = :returnAction ]

This is the query:

```
    em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT new returnitRest.Ereturn(e.rma, e.shipper, e.carrier, e.returnAction) FROM ereturn e " +
            "JOIN FETCH e.productItems pi " +
            "WHERE e.status = 'RECEIVED' AND " +
            "e.shipper.email = :shipper AND " +
            "e.carrier.email = :carrier AND " +
            "pi.returnAction = :returnAction ")
            .setParameter("shipper", shipperEmail)
            .setParameter("carrier", issuer)
            .setParameter("returnAction", ReturnAction.valueOf(returnAction))
            .getResultList();
```

**QUESTIONS:**

- Who is the missing owner of the association?
- What can I do to fix this query and still use DTO for performance gain and join fetch?

thank you very much

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Let me know if you had a resolution to this.

Comment: Im not sure if I got it right, probably someone with more experience can help but If I'm not mistaken DTO can only access the ROOT element (in my case it is Ereturn) so ProductItems is not accessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not make JOIN to work on a @OneToMany relationship so instead I did the otherway around which is using the @ManyToOne relationship. This way worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a join fetch here, you are not even using the product item in the DTO. A normal join would be enough, that way, you also won't see that error.